# If my neighbour wants to build on the boundary line can he enter my property to construct it?

Tags: victoria

If under the Planning and Environment Act of Victoria is there any provision for the owner of an adjacent property to enter another property in order to build a structure on his property.

The neighbour wants to render a brick wall built 50mm from the boundary line. I told him that he cannot and that he should of thought of that earlier.

Comment: Victoria where? Canada, Australia, etc?

Comment: I'm not sure about Victoria, but many places in the US have minimum setbacks from property lines, you would have to ask a local office if this applies in your area.